# Data wrangling: reshape dataframe so that multiple values in cells become distinct rows

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My data looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kURd2.jpg)

```
X            Y   Z    A          B         C
Qualify     10  35  us01    us03,ud05   um90,ug09
Identify    20  23  us02    us06, us01  us91,us93,us95
```

But data has to be changed to display as below. So that the data inside the cells become rows. But some cells have singular values while some have multiple separated by comma. So dynamically, they need to change and be put into a new row with duplication of the same data from the other columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaTY.jpg)

```
Identifier  Role    X       Y   Z
us01         A   Qualify    10  35
us03         B   Qualify    10  35
us05         B   Qualify    10  35
um90         C   Qualify    10  35
ug09         C   Qualify    10  35
```

I tried `cSplit` but it did not work and got worse actually.

Comment: "pivotting/unpivotting" could be done with `melt` and `cast` (for good performance when using big data tables use the `data.table` package which provide a good implementation of these functions)

Answer (score 0):

## See comment by @alistaire below for a better solution

Does this work using `tidyr/dplyr` where df id your data frame:

```
df %>% separate(B, into=c("B1","B2")) %>%
       separate(C, into=c("C1","C2","C3")) %>%
       gather(Role,Id,A:C3)
```

gives this;

```
          X     Y     Z  Role    Id
      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1   Qualify    10    35     A  us01
2  Identify    20    23     A  us02
3   Qualify    10    35    B1  us03
4  Identify    20    23    B1  us06
5   Qualify    10    35    B2  ud05
6  Identify    20    23    B2  us01
7   Qualify    10    35    C1  um90
8  Identify    20    23    C1  us91
9   Qualify    10    35    C2  ug09
10 Identify    20    23    C2  us93
11  Qualify    10    35    C3  <NA>
12 Identify    20    23    C3  us95
```

Comment: Not sure if the number of values in columns A, B and C vary in length or are the same as in the question.

Comment: Thanks so much! But what if we don't know how many separate values are there under B or C? Or there are more number values than previously thought under those columns. And instead of B1/B2 or C1/C2/C3; can't I get the same value in all. So value B as a row cell in new dataframe for all the values under B column in original data.

Comment: The values under A,B, and C vary in length.

Comment: The separate function is separating the values based on the ",". So all you need is the max length of the comma separated values in the string and pass it into separate.  For unequal lengths it is now generating NAs for missing values. For same Role names try this : df %>% separate(B, into=c(rep("B",2))) %>% separate(C, into=c("C1","C2","C3")) %>%gather(Role,Id,A:C3)

Comment: `gather` first, then use `separate_rows`: `df %>% gather(Role, Identifier, A:C) %>% separate_rows(Identifier)`

Comment: Thanks so much! I think it worked. Now I am editing it to run on the huge dataset; hopefully it will run without a hitch!

Comment: @alistaire This is better. Didn't know about separate_rows. Edited accordingly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very naive way to get the required output. Surely not the best solution, but I guess it gets what you want.

Calling the dataset as `data`.

```
data <- tidyr::gather(data, "Role", "Identifier", 4:6)
data2 <- strsplit(data$Identifier, split = ",")
data2 <- data.frame(X = rep(data$X, sapply(data2, length)),
                    Y = rep(data$Y, sapply(data2, length)),
                    Z = rep(data$Z, sapply(data2, length)),
                    Role = rep(data$Role, sapply(data2, length)),
                    Identifier = unlist(data2))
```

Comment: Got an error when I tried this method. Maybe I am doing something wrong. But the above solution worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: I just checked the code again with the same dataset. It seems to be working fine. What is the error that you got? And yes, the solution in the comments is a way better way to solve this.